# Приложение вылетает при переходе на активность

Tags: java, android, activity

Здравствуйте, я начинающий программист. И я решил сделать проект, в котором от выбора сложности  будут создаваться примеры. Я создал класс и в нем создал ключ и константы, а в активности  перехожу на другую активность смотря от нажатой кнопки создаю пример. 
Но почему то при выборе сложности приложение вылетает.
Логи:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.konter.random, PID: 14168
E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.konter.random/com.konter.random.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
E   AndroidRuntime                               at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.konter.random.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:120)
E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259)
E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 11 more
```

HomeActivity (первое активити):

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity
{
    Button play,easyBuutton,mediumButton,hardButton;
    LinearLayout lin;
    LinearLayout lin2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
    play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.homeButton);
    easyBuutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.easyButton);
    mediumButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mediumButton);
    hardButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.hardButton);
    lin=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id. outAnim);
    lin2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.inAnim);
        final Animation fallingAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.one);
        final Animation fallingAnimation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.two);

        fallingAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation p1)
                {
                    // TODO: Implement this method
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation p1)
                {
                    lin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    lin2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    lin2.startAnimation(fallingAnimation1); 
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation p1)
                {
                    // TODO: Implement this method
                }
                });                                                 
        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1)
                {
                lin.startAnimation(fallingAnimation);
                    }
                });
        OnClickListener complication= new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                switch(v.getId()){
                    case R.id.easyButton:
                        perehod(Level.EASY_START,Level.EASY_END);
                        break;
                    case R.id.mediumButton:
                        perehod(Level.MEDIUM_START,Level.MEDIUM_END);
                        break;
                    case R.id.hardButton:
                        perehod(Level.HARD_START,Level.HARD_END);
                        break;
                }
            }
                };
                easyBuutton.setOnClickListener(complication);
                mediumButton.setOnClickListener(complication);
                hardButton.setOnClickListener(complication);
        }
        void perehod(int start,int end){
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Level.LEVEL_START,start);
            intent.putExtra(Level.LEVEL_END,end);
            startActivity(intent)
        }
}
```

MainActivity (второе активити, в котором происходит выбор рандомного числа, вычитание и сравнивание):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    //int a=0,b=100
    int c,z;
    int s=16000;
    final int start = getIntent().getIntExtra(Level.LEVEL_START,0);
    final int end = getIntent().getIntExtra(Level.LEVEL_END, 1);
    TextView  mainTextView, mainTextView1,time;
    Button one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,zero,delit,minus,inspection;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        regist();
        soz_primer();
        new CountDownTimer(16000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //тут пиши то, что будет выполняться каждую секунду
                time.setText(""+millisUntilFinished/1000);
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                //тут пиши то, что должно произойти когда таймер закончит работу
                time.setText("0");

            }
        }.start();
                final OnClickListener button=new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String text=((Button)v).getText().toString();
                mainTextView1.append(""+text);  
            }
            };
            one.setOnClickListener(button);
            two.setOnClickListener(button);
            three.setOnClickListener(button);
            four.setOnClickListener(button);
            five.setOnClickListener(button);
            six.setOnClickListener(button);
            seven.setOnClickListener(button);
            eight.setOnClickListener(button);
            nine.setOnClickListener(button);
            zero.setOnClickListener(button);
            minus.setOnClickListener(button);
        delit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1)
                {
                    mainTextView1.setText("");
                }


            });
        inspection.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1)
                {
                    z=Integer.parseInt(mainTextView1.getText().toString());

                        if(c==z){
                            mainTextView1.setText("");
                            soz_primer();
                            int v=Integer.parseInt(time.getText().toString());
                        }

                    else finish();

                }


            });
    }
    void regist(){
        one=(Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
        two=(Button)findViewById(R.id.two);
        three=(Button)findViewById(R.id.three);
        four=(Button)findViewById(R.id.four);
        five=(Button)findViewById(R.id.five);
        six=(Button)findViewById(R.id.six);
        seven=(Button)findViewById(R.id.seven);
        eight=(Button)findViewById(R.id.eight);
        nine=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nine);
        zero=(Button)findViewById(R.id.zero);
        delit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.delit);
        minus=(Button)findViewById(R.id.minus);
        time=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
        mainTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);
        mainTextView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainTextView1);
        inspection=(Button)findViewById(R.id.inspection);
        }
        void soz_primer(){
            //int random_number = start + (int) (Math.random() * end); 
            //int random_number1 = start+ (int) (Math.random() * end); 

            int random_number=new Random().nextInt(start)+end;
            int random_number1=new Random().nextInt(start)+end;
            mainTextView.setText(""+random_number);
            int i=(int)(Math.random()*2);
            if(i==0){
                c=random_number+random_number1;
                mainTextView.append("+");
            }else
                mainTextView.append("-");   
            mainTextView.append(""+random_number1+"=");
                c=random_number-random_number1;
            }
        }
```

Класс с ключами и константами:

```
public class Level
{
    public static String LEVEL_START="level_start";
    public static String LEVEL_END="level_end";
public static int EASY_START=0;
public static int EASY_END=100;
public static int MEDIUM_START=100;
public static int MEDIUM_END=1000;
public static int HARD_START=900;
public static int HARD_END=10000;
}
```

Comment: В манифесте вторая активность прописана?

Answer (score 3):

```
void perehod(int start,int end){
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        intent.putExtra(Level.LEVEL_START,start);
        intent.putExtra(Level.LEVEL_END,end);
    }
```

Вас не смущает, что вы сперва запускаете активити с пустыми extras, а только после этого пытаетесь в них что-то запихать?

Правильно будет так

```
void perehod(int start,int end){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Level.LEVEL_START,start);
        intent.putExtra(Level.LEVEL_END,end);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

И вот эти штуки в onCreate переместите

```
start = getIntent().getIntExtra(Level.LEVEL_START,0);
end = getIntent().getIntExtra(Level.LEVEL_END, 1);
```

Дело в том, что переменные класса инициализируются в момент инстанцирования класса, в том момент, когда getIntent() ничего кроме null вернуть еще не может.

Comment: Оно все равно вылетает

Comment: Черт, опередили! ;)

Comment: `HomeActivity.this - это ересь какая то.` – а почему ересь?

Comment: @post_zeew Ну с ересью погорячился конечно, но а зачем оно в методе класса?

Comment: @rjhdby, В данном случае оно не нужно, но ересью я бы это не назвал.

Answer (score 1):

Вынесите инициализацию переменных в `onCreate`.

```
int start, end...

onCreate() { ...
Intent i = getIntent();
start = i.getIntExtra(Level.LEVEL_START, 0);
end = i.getIntExtra(Level.LEVEL_END, 0);
... }
```

@rjhdby в своем ответе тоже верно подметил, но этл второй момент